# XSLT - Combinations of all element attributes for CSS-Stylesheet

Tags: html, css, xml, xslt

I was wondering if the following is possible to do via XSLT. I'm fairly new to it.

Say I have a element with various possible attributes. For each combination of attributes I want to show speudo-content.

Element with various attributes:

```
<!ATTLIST foo
     apple CDATA #IMPLIED 
     peach CDATA #IMPLIED
     kiwi  CDATA #IMPLIED
     ...
>
```

Desired CSS:

```
foo[apple]:before {
    content: '@apple: ' attr(apple);
}
foo[peach]:before {
    content: '@peach: ' attr(peach);
}
foo[kiwi]:before {
    content: '@kiwi: ' attr(kiwi);
}
foo[apple][peach]:before {
    content: '@apple: ' attr(apple) ' @peach: ' attr(peach);
}
foo[apple][kiwi]:before {
    content: '@apple: ' attr(apple) ' @kiwi: ' attr(kiwi);
}
foo[peach][kiwi]:before {
    content: '@apple: ' attr(peach) ' @kiwi: ' attr(kiwi);
}
foo[apple][peach][kiwi]:before {
    content: '@apple: ' attr(apple) ' @peach: ' attr(peach) ' @kiwi: ' attr(kiwi);
}
```

The order doesn't really matter, but each combination should only occur once. There are some elements with more than five attributes, so getting all the combinations for the CSS through XSLT would be quite helpful. Unfortunately js is not an option in my case, output got to be plain CSS2.

I can't wrap my mind around how to solve this problem,any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSLT is a bad choice for this kind of problem. It's better to use a general-purpose programming language. The combinations can be represented with a bit field containing a bit for each attribute. Then you can run through numbers 1 to 2^n-1 to enumerate all the combinations.

Here's a Javascript example:

```js
function generateCss(items) {
  var n = items.length;
  var m = 1 << n; // 2^n
  
  document.write('<pre>');

  for (var i = 1; i < m; i++) {
    var subset = items.filter(function(item, index) {
      // (1 << index) is the bit representing the current item.
      return i & (1 << index);
    });

    var attrs = subset.map(function(item) {
      return '[' + item + ']';
    }).join('');

    var content = subset.map(function(item, index) {
      return "'" + (index == 0 ? '' : ' ') + '@' + item +
             ": ' attr(" + item + ")";
    }).join(' ');

    document.write(
      'foo' + attrs + ':before {\n' +
      '  content: ' + content + ';\n' +
      '}\n');
  }

  document.write('</pre>');
}

generateCss([ 'apple', 'peach', 'kiwi' ]);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You´re a lifesaver!